# I created a new Google account. How can I migrate my android device to use this new account?

Tags: google-account, google

I just made a new Google account, and I wish to migrate my android device to use this new account for Google Play et al. I've spent about an hour researching this so far, and the only answer I've found thus far is to factory reset my device.

This is not a viable solution, as I have thousands of apps, contacts, and other personal data that would take far too long to recover, and doing so would be inefficient. Surely the folks at Google have developed a smart way to go about this.

There must be some kind of way to simply "log out" and "log in".

How might I do this?

Comment: The truth is that I need to access google services (namely: Play) to deal with a friend's rooted (smh) android device. I was going to use my own account, but then I realized that I've never actually logged out on my own phone. So I looked around, and realized: I have absolutely no idea how to "swap" accounts. I would like to fix this device for them, but I obviously can't give a device with my account on it to someone else. That's a pretty huge security risk. I also realize that this situation could come up in the future for myself, hence the generalized scenario.

Comment: You can have multiple Android devices signed in to your Google account. And you can also easily remove your account from your friends phone from `Settings -> Accounts & Sync`, where you can also tell it not to synchronize your sensitive data with his phone.

Comment: @AaronGillion Thanks for the tip! Might you want to add it as an answer?

Comment: Sure, well, maybe I didn't ***want*** to (haha), but after finding some useful illustrations I decided to make an answer out of it. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have **multiple Android devices** signed in to your Google account, as observed in Play Store's Device Manager:

[image: Play Store Devices]

You can also **easily remove your account** from your friends phone from `Settings -> Accounts & Sync`, where you can also instruct the phone not to synchronize your sensitive data with his phone (ex. sync Family Calendar but not App Data or Contacts!)

In this screenshot, the "Remove" button is on the top-right after you hit your menu key.

[image: Accounts & Sync]

Hope this clears up your concerns!